# Swift 'NilLiteralConvertible' error: Optional class type

Tags: swift, null, option-type

In StoryViewController.swift:

```
var story :Story?

if story != nil {...}// ERROR: Type UInt8 doer not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
```

In Story.swift:

```
class Story {
      var title: String
      var content: String

      init(title: String, content: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
      }

      func description() -> String {
        return title
      }


      class func loadStories(completion: ((Array<Story>?, NSErrorPointer) -> Void)!) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
          var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
          let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
          let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

          var stories = [Story]()

          if let contents = manager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: error) {
            error = nil

            for file in contents {
              if file.hasSuffix(".grm") {
                let filePath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file as String)
                let title = file.stringByDeletingPathExtension
                let content = NSString(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: error)

                let story = Story(title: title, content: content)
            if error != nil {
              break
            }

            stories.append(story)

            error = nil
          }
        }
      }

      stories.sort({ a, b in
        a.title < b.title
      })

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         if error != nil {
          completion(nil, error)
        } else {
          completion(stories, nil)
        }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Am I write it right? How can I fix the error:"Type UInt8 doer not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'" in StoryViewController.swift? Thanks a lot!

more: I just want to check whether the story file is empty. And if it's not, show info in the view. The code above successfully ran before Swift beta3 released. I guess may be the new NilLiteralConvertible protocal cause this error.

/*************************************************/
I download this project from http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Grimm-Swift.zip as my exercise from a bbs. If you run this version without any modified you'll noticed the error above. Thanks the creator of this project.
/*************************************************/

Comment: You're probably omitting what is causing the error, because that code looks good and (with some obvious modifications) it works on playground

Comment: I think you need to expand `{...}` for us

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: The example compiles just fine with Xcode 6.0 and 6.1. What's the code in `{...}`? The Swift compiler sometimes reports errors unrelated to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]use this

```
var story: Story?
story = Story (title: "Stack", content: "overflow")

if story != nil {
    println("It's not nil!")
}
else {
    println("It's nil!")
}
```

Comment: @OzzieChen to know more about swift literal convertible you can read the recent article by [Mattt Thompson](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/)

Comment: It worked! But why it can run successfully though I delete the code you told me when I reopen the project.... Anyway, thank you to help the freshman like me:)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Class` with `class`.

If this is not the cause please post more code.